# How to jump into the System Settings from my application in iOS6?

Tags: ios5, settings, system, ios6

Why can't I use syntax like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]]
```

to jump into the System Settings from my application in iOS6 but I can in iOS5? Is there any official information about this (for example from developer.apple.com)? Thanks!